# Wordpress, inserting table rows from csv-formatted txt file

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

Currently working on a wordpress plugin that will allow the insertion of a txt file in a csv format into a custom table in the wordpress database.

I previously used a command to create the table and the columns with the appropriate datatypes.  This is an example of a table I'm creating:

```
global $gtfs_db_version;
$gtfs_db_version = '1.0';

function routes_install() {
global $wpdb;
global $gtfs_db_version;
$table_name = 'routes_txt';

$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
    id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    route_long_name varchar(80) NOT NULL,
    route_type  varchar(80),
    route_text_color    varchar(80),
    route_color varchar(80),
    agency_id   varchar(80),
    route_id    varchar(80),
    route_url   varchar(80),
    route_short_name    varchar(80),
    PRIMARY KEY  (id)
) $charset_collate;";

require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
dbDelta( $sql );

add_option( 'gtfs_db_version', $gtfs_db_version );
};
```

Now, in the command where I am creating the table rows from the txt file, there is a chance the column order will be different every time a new txt file is available.  This is where the problem can occur.    Right now, I have to manually change the column assignment in the command.  The first row does have the column names as it's being inserted, if that helps.

```
function insert_routes(){
global $wpdb;
$path_name =   get_option( "routes_txt" );
$table_name = 'routes_txt';
$firstline = array_shift(file($path_name));
$file_array = file($path_name);
$file_line_num = 1;
foreach ($file_array as $file_array_value) {
      $number_of_lines =  count($file_array); // number of lines in txt file
      $file_array_value = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $file_array_value);

      //if first line of file that has tables column names
      $stringArray = explode(",",$file_array_value);
      if($file_line_num == 1){
          echo '';
      }else{

                    $route_id = array_values($stringArray)[0];
                    $route_short_name = array_values($stringArray)[1];
                    $route_long_name = array_values($stringArray)[2];
                    $route_type = array_values($stringArray)[3];
                    $route_url = array_values($stringArray)[4];
                    $agency_id = array_values($stringArray)[5];
                    $route_color = array_values($stringArray)[6];
                    $route_text_color = array_values($stringArray)[7];

         //puts everything seperated by a comma in a array

            $wpdb->replace( 
                $table_name, 
                array( 
                    'id' => $file_line_num,
                    'route_long_name' => $route_long_name,
                    'route_type' => $route_type,
                    'route_text_color' => $route_text_color,
                    'route_color' => $route_color,
                    'agency_id' => $agency_id,
                    'route_id' => $route_id,
                    'route_url' => $route_url,
                    'route_short_name' => $route_short_name
                )    
            );

        }

        $file_line_num++;
      }

};
```

Is there a way with a SQL command to assign the correct columns to the correct pre-designated columns?

EDIT: as requested, the first couple of lines of two different versions of the routes_txt csv.

Version 1

```
route_long_name, route_type, route_text_color, route_color, agency_id, route_id, route_url, route_short_name
, 3, FFFFFF, 008C9B, NCTD, 318, http://www.gonctd.com/breeze, 318
, 3, FFFFFF, 008C9B, NCTD, 313, http://www.gonctd.com/breeze, 313
```

Version 2

```
route_id, route_short_name, route_long_name, route_type, route_url, agency_id, route_color, route_text_color
301, 101, ,3, http://www.gonctd.com/breeze, NCTD, 008C9B, FFFFFF
302, 302, ,3, http://www.gonctd.com/breeze, NCTD, 008C9B, FFFFFF
```

And before you ask, asking the people in charge of creating these CSV's to keep with a consistent column paradigm is not possible(I know, right? ARG!)

Comment: Note: Try and use `VARCHAR(255)` as a default and only restrict that if you have a very compelling reason. For many things, like names and email addresses, shorter fields can cause huge hassles for your users.

Comment: It's also extremely odd to see `MEDIUMINT` used here. Just use `INT`. Shaving one byte off that column doesn't really save you anything, machines these days are 64-bit by default so a 24-bit value doesn't matter.

Comment: Actually parsing the fields from lines in .csv files is surprisingly hard to get right. Consider using the built-in function. http://php.net/fgetcsv   (Do it yourself with `explode()`, etc, you *will* be sorry. Don't ask how I know this.) And, it will help if you show us a few lines of several of these csv files with columns in different orders. Include the column headers.

Comment: added the requested info